# Invalid signature in mined transaction (txid 0xde26b1deeb157c634ad06d08cc4e533d663496a25c75443e10c1fe0e760cd0a5)

Tags: signature, ecdsa

I have a encounter a stranged transaction with an invalid signature. This transaction has been registered in the block chain.

Here the transaction in etherscan : https://etherscan.io/tx/0xde26b1deeb157c634ad06d08cc4e533d663496a25c75443e10c1fe0e760cd0a5

The raw transaction is :

```
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
```

I used an online transaction decoder (https://toolkit.abdk.consulting/ethereum) and it shows really low r and s values (`2d` and `4f`). Is I am not mistaken those values must be at least 32 bytes in order to form a valid signature.

Can someone point out to me what I have missed ?

Answer (score 0):

The values `r = 2d` and `s = 4f` are valid as 32 bytes by padding with 0 to the left, so the function `ECRecovery(SignedTransaction, Signature)` will return a valid address.

Note: If you trace the sender it will lead to a Vitalik address.